# Doing Internal Requests with Zend Framework 1.11

Tags: zend-framework

I need todo internal requests to other controllers in my zend framework project.

I have investigated Action helpers todo this but none seem to work.

My project is an API. This API sometimes duplicates its output.

Example:
/client.json: returns a list of clients the user can access
/client/tree.json returns a tree of clients

To cut down on Model code and extra queries rebinding data /client/tree.json would be better to do an internal call to /client.json to fetch the cleaned client list there.

Zends documentation says something like this:

```
    $request = clone $this->getRequest();
    $request->setActionName('get')
        ->setControllerName('tree')
        ->setParams(array('bar' => 'baz'));
$this->_helper->actionStack($request);
```

However it doesnt state how to extract the data from that request. If I

```
print_r($this->_helper->actionStack($request));
```

I just get a ton of Zend garbage

Comment: Could you possibly post some code that might help explain what you are asking? I'm having a problem understanding what an internal request of a controller might be, as controllers in and of themselves shouldn't really do anything.

Comment: Updated, thanks for replying.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't something that should be done in a controller. It should be handled in the model. The model supplies the data, in this case a client list or a client tree. Only the model should ever provide that data. What you want to accomplish is actually a form of caching. You can cache that data in many different ways both inside and outside of your model or application.

You might want to start by exploring how to implement an [identity map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_map_pattern) inside of your models.

```
class someBaseMapper
//an identity map can be as simple as a protected class variable with accessors
 protected $map = array();

 /**
     * Set value and name of entity in identity map.
     *
     * @param string $id
     * @param object $entity
     */
 protected function setMap($id, $entity)
    {
        $this->map[$id] = $entity;
    }

    /**
     * Get value of entity id from identity map.
     *
     * @param string $id
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getMap($id)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($id, $this->map)) {
            return $this->map[$id];
        }
    }
```

Then to use your map:

```
//later in the same mapper
public function findById($id)
{
    //check map requested id
    if ($this->getMap($id)) {
        return $this->getMap($id);
    }
    //if no map match
    $select = $this->getGateway()->select();
    $select->where('id = ?', $id);

    $row = $this->getGateway()->fetchRow($select);
    //create entity
    $entity = $this->createEntity($row);
    //add new entity to map
    $this->setMap($row->id, $entity);

    return $entity;
}
```

also you can check out [Zend_cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.introduction.html) for database or page caching.
There are also several external caching tools available for PHP that you may find interesting.

Comment: Yes to some degree, I'm using Propel and it handles a lot of this for me. However I dont fully agree as it doesn't answer my question. I still want todo internal calls within my API and need a real solution for that.

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood your question. Sorry.